# mamp security Mac

Tags: wordpress, apache, mamp

I was wondering if it's possible to make it so that the server I run with Mamp cannot access files outside the folder I use for my development. I currently use the free version but if it's really simple to do with PRO I wouldn't mind updating.

I don't like the fact that Mamp currently has access to all my folders.

Comment: Do you mean restricting the files that can be served from Apache, or limiting its access to the rest of your drive, e.g. chroot, or running from a Docker container?

Comment: I mean that currently php files I run with Mamp can access files on the rest of my drive. So they can go above the root folder of the website. I would like to restrict this if possible.